# Trying to populate array with string values based on filter selections, and filter records by comparing the array to string value of record attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have an API response that returns a list of records each with a 'status' attribute. The status can be 'current', 'former', 'never'.

I have a set of 3 checkboxes that each carry a value for the same that a user would click to filter the list of records accordingly.

The way I'm trying to achieve the filtering functionality is by using a hook for `const [statuses, setStatuses] = useState<string[]>([]);`

And then populating that array with the value of each checkbox from:

```
<div>FILTER BY STATUS</div>
 <FilterSection>
  <span><input type="checkbox" value="Current" onClick={handleStatusChange}/> Current</span>
  <span><input type="checkbox" value="Former" onClick={handleStatusChange}/> Former</span>
  <span><input type="checkbox" value="Never" onClick={handleStatusChange}/> Never </span>
 </FilterSection>
</div>
```

I then have the onClick method that calls handleStatusChange:

```
  const handleStatusChange = e => {
    setStatuses([...statuses, e.target.value]);
    props.onFilterChange(statuses, state)
    console.log('status value: ', e.target.value)
  };
```

Which passes it's values up to the container component and feeds into the filter function which looks like:

```
  const handleFilterChange = (status: string[], state: string) => {
    store.set('currentPage')(0);
    const allLocations = store.get('locations');
    let filteredLocations = allLocations.slice();
    const pageSize = store.get('pageSize');

    if (status && status.length > 0) {
      filteredLocations = filteredLocations
        .filter(l => {
          l.financialDetails && l.financialDetails.locationStatus === status;
        })
        .slice();
    }

    store.set('filteredLocations')(filteredLocations);
    const pagedLocations = filteredLocations.slice(0, pageSize);
    store.set('pagedLocations')(pagedLocations);
    store.set('locationsLoading')(false);
  };
```

The problem I'm seeing is that I get a TypeScript error inside `handleFilterChange` saying `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'string[]' have no overlap.`

**EDIT**
I've updated the `handleStatusChange` function and it's populating the array but only on the second click of a checkbox. So on first click it produces an empty array, on second click it grabs whatever the first clicked value was and pushes it into the array so that it's always one click behind what a user actually selected.

Comment: Isn't the call to `setStatuses(e.target.value);` in the `handleStatusChange` method attempting to set the statuses to a string? That is, `e.target.value` is a string, but `statuses` is a string array.

Comment: I updated that line to be ```setStatuses([e.target.value])``` but I'm still only populating a single element at a time

Comment: Can you edit the sample code in the post? If I take my understanding from your comment, what you're doing now is setting statuses to an array with a single value. To add a value to the statuses array you can do this `setStatuses([...statuses, e.target.value])`. But what happens when the user wants to remove a filter (unselect a status)? I'm thinking you'll need to remove a status if it's already in the array.

Comment: Yeup I'll update it now, and I haven't even gotten that far in the logic

Comment: Is your `handleFilterChange` method working properly?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, I'm getting a TypeScript error on this line: ```filteredLocations = filteredLocations
        .filter(l => {
          l.financialDetails && l.financialDetails.locationStatus === status;
        })
        .slice();``` stating that ```This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'string[]' have no overlap.ts(2367)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207549/discussion-between-jason-and-josh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work.

```js
const handleStatusChange = e => {
  const status = e.target.value;

  if (!statuses.includes(status)) {
    setStatuses(statuses.concat(status));
  }
  else {
    const statusIndex = statuses.findIndex(status);
    statuses.splice(statusIndex, 1);
    setStatuses(statuses);
  }

  props.onFilterChange(statuses)
};
```

And for the handleFilterChange...

```
  const handleFilterChange = (statuses: string[]) => {
    const allLocations = store.get('locations');
    let filteredLocations = allLocations.slice();

    if (statuses && statuses.length) {
      statuses.forEach((status) => {
        filteredLocations = filteredLocations
          .filter(l => (l.financialDetails && l.financialDetails.locationStatus !== status));
    }

    const pagedLocations = filteredLocations.slice(0, pageSize);
  };
```

I removed some of the code I thought was irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Just added that and I'm getting a TypeScript error for ```.filter(l => {
l.financialDetails && l.financialDetails.locationStatus === status;
});``` that says ```Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression```

Comment: Updated: fixed syntax and filtering condition.

Comment: That did it! I had to mess around with some of other logic to include other filtered conditions but this was a huge help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  const handleStatusChange = e => {
    const updatedStatus = [...statuses, e.target.value];
    props.onFilterChange(updatedStatus, state)
    setStatuses(updatedStatus);
    console.log('status value: ', e.target.value)
  };
```

you always should call parent (props function) to pass state to parent because when you call `setStatuses` at that time statuses array is empty so call that 
`props.onFilterChange` 
first before setting state.

or in functional component you can use `useEffect` like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
   props.onFilterChange(statuses, state);
},[statuses]);
```